# Quasar tags input

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

```
<q-input outlined v-model="tags" label="Add tags">
   <template #prepend>
      <q-badge v-for="tag in tags"> {{ tag }} </q-badge>
   </template>
</q-input>
```

This is q-input from quasar frame work i'm trying to make every word as a tag

I tried in script that the tags model will be array of objects or just array but it ends with every letter in tag alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input element returns a single string value. `typeof (tags) === 'string'`. When you loop over a string value, `v-for` iterates over its characters (one by one).

To show every entered value as a tag, you need to store the history of different inputs in a separate array.

A very simple solution can be:

```html
<temlapte>
<q-input outlined v-model="tag" @keydown.enter="saveTag" label="Add tags">
  <template #prepend>
    <q-badge v-for="tag in tagList" :key="tag"> {{ tag }}</q-badge>
  </template>
</q-input>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

const tag = ref('');
const tagList = ref<Array<string>>([]);

function saveTag() {
  if (!!tag.value?.trim()) {
    tagList.value.push(tag.value);
    tag.value = '';
  }
}
</script>
```

Here, I save every tag after pressing the enter key.

The `tagList` array contains all your tags for further use.